# Align button at the bottom of div

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, joomla3.0

I am having trouble trying to get the button in each div "**.inductees**" to sit at the bottom it. The height of the div is set after the document is loaded via a [javascript](https://github.com/Sam152/Javascript-Equal-Height-Responsive-Rows) that takes the largest height and sets the rest equal to it. Thus my problem of how to get it to the bottom. I have tried several methods but they all break the Bootstrap columns.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yoderman94/8ta32wa0/1/)**

**CSS**

```
.inductees {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.inductees .info-text {
    color: #494743;
    padding: 10px;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div style="height: 611px;" class="inductees">
                <img alt="Shelmer Doyle Blackburn J" src="http://placehold.it/600x700" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="info-text">
                    <p class="name">Shelmer Doyle Blackburn Jr.</p>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li>Year Inducted: 2014</li>
                        <li>Blackburn established The Blackburn Family Foundation Charitable Organization. He is the former Chairman of Adult Enrichment Services of Wilkes County and was instrumental in the establishment of the Ruby Pardue Blackburn Adult Day Care.</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="center"><a href="#"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">See More</button></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div style="height: 611px;" class="inductees">
                <img alt="Zachary Knight Galifianakis" src="http://placehold.it/600x700" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="info-text">
                    <p class="name">Zachary Knight Galifianakis</p>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li>Year Inducted: 2014</li>
                        <li>Galifianakis’ career began on television, and he currently thrives in the film industry as an award-winning supporting actor.</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="center"><a href="#"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">See More</button></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div style="height: 611px;" class="inductees">
                <img alt="Shelmer Doyle Blackburn J" src="http://placehold.it/600x700" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="info-text">
                    <p class="name">Shelmer Doyle Blackburn Jr.</p>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li>Year Inducted: 2014</li>
                        <li>Blackburn established The Blackburn Family Foundation Charitable Organization. He is the former Chairman of Adult Enrichment Services of Wilkes County and was instrumental in the establishment of the Ruby Pardue Blackburn Adult Day Care.</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="center"><a href="#"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">See More</button></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div style="height: 611px;" class="inductees">
                <img alt="Zachary Knight Galifianakis" src="http://placehold.it/600x700" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="info-text">
                    <p class="name">Zachary Knight Galifianakis</p>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li>Year Inducted: 2014</li>
                        <li>Galifianakis’ career began on television, and he currently thrives in the film industry as an award-winning supporting actor.</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="center"><a href="#"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">See More</button></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried vertical-align:bottom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add another class that absolute positions the parent div of the button. Then set bottom: 0, and the width 100% to allow to still center.

For instance something like:

```css
.alignBottom {
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

JSFiddle here to see it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/5hd7ow7p/2/

Comment: For anyone who comes across this in the future, I added an extra div (.inductees-wrapper) around the entire block and applied a position relative and then used the solution above for the button.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add 2 css

```
.inductees{
    position:relative;
}
.inductees .btn{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:15px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were closing the inductee info text div tags after the button, so the button was layering ontop.

Make sure the text div is seperate to the button. This is the updated version, edit the margin and padding for the info-text divs and button divs to center them. But this answers your question.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div style="height: 611px;" class="inductees">
                    <img alt="Shelmer Doyle Blackburn J" src="http://placehold.it/600x700" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="info-text">
                        <p class="name">Shelmer Doyle Blackburn Jr.</p>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li>Year Inducted: 2014</li>
                            <li>Blackburn established The Blackburn Family Foundation Charitable Organization. He is the former Chairman of Adult Enrichment Services of Wilkes County and was instrumental in the establishment of the Ruby Pardue Blackburn Adult Day Care.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="center"><a href="#"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">See More</button></a>

                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div style="height: 611px;" class="inductees">
                    <img alt="Zachary Knight Galifianakis" src="http://placehold.it/600x700" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="info-text">
                        <p class="name">Zachary Knight Galifianakis</p>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li>Year Inducted: 2014</li>
                            <li>Galifianakis’ career began on television, and he currently thrives in the film industry as an award-winning supporting actor.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="center"><a href="#"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">See More</button></a> </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div style="height: 611px;" class="inductees">
                    <img alt="Shelmer Doyle Blackburn J" src="http://placehold.it/600x700" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="info-text">
                        <p class="name">Shelmer Doyle Blackburn Jr.</p>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li>Year Inducted: 2014</li>
                            <li>Blackburn established The Blackburn Family Foundation Charitable Organization. He is the former Chairman of Adult Enrichment Services of Wilkes County and was instrumental in the establishment of the Ruby Pardue Blackburn Adult Day Care.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="center"><a href="#"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">See More</button></a>

                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div style="height: 611px;" class="inductees">
                    <img alt="Zachary Knight Galifianakis" src="http://placehold.it/600x700" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="info-text">
                        <p class="name">Zachary Knight Galifianakis</p>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li>Year Inducted: 2014</li>
                            <li>Galifianakis’ career began on television, and he currently thrives in the film industry as an award-winning supporting actor.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="center"><a href="#"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">See More</button></a>

                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.inductees {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.inductees .info-text {
    color: #494743;
}
.center {
    vertical-align:center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.center button {height:100%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ta32wa0/3/